# VitualBox showing fatal error in mykernel.iso

Tags: assembly, makefile, linker, operating-system, virtualbox

I am currently working on an Operating System. I am a beginner and everyone has to start somewhere. The following files were coded:**kernel.cpp** **loader.s** **linker.ld** **types.h** **Makefile**. I opened up terminal and ran these commands later: `make kernel.o` `make loader.o` `make mykernel.bin` and `make mykernel.iso` 
After running make `mykernel.iso`, I created a .iso image whose path I provided to the VirtualBox Machine. But,when my OS boots, it shows this error on VirtualBox:

**FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium! SYSTEM HALTED.**
Can anyone help me debug the code? Please I am a student and fascinated by operating systems.

and these are my files:

---

**kernel.cpp:**

```
#include "types.h"

void printf(char* str)
{
    static uint16_t* VideoMemory = (uint16_t*)0xb8000;

    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        VideoMemory[i] = (VideoMemory[i] & 0xFF00) | str[i];
}



typedef void (*constructor)();
extern "C" constructor start_ctors;
extern "C" constructor end_ctors;
extern "C" void callConstructors()
{
    for(constructor* i = &start_ctors; i != &end_ctors; i++)
        (*i)();
}



extern "C" void kernelMain(const void* multiboot_structure, uint32_t /*multiboot_magic*/)
{
    printf("Hello World! --- http://www.AlgorithMan.de");

    while(1);
}
```

---

Following is a file named **"linker.ld**"

```
linker.ld

ENTRY(loader)
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:i386)

SECTIONS
{
  . = 0x0100000;

  .text :
  {
    *(.multiboot)
    *(.text*)
    *(.rodata)
  }

  .data  :
  {
    start_ctors = .;
    KEEP(*( .init_array ));
    KEEP(*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY( .init_array.* )));
    end_ctors = .;

    *(.data)
  }

  .bss  :
  {
    *(.bss)
  }

  /DISCARD/ : { *(.fini_array*) *(.comment) }
}
```

---

My **"loader.s"**:

```
.set MAGIC, 0x1badb002
.set FLAGS, (1<<0 | 1<<1)
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS)

.section .multiboot
    .long MAGIC
    .long FLAGS
    .long CHECKSUM


.section .text
.extern kernelMain
.extern callConstructors
.global loader


loader:
    mov $kernel_stack, %esp
    call callConstructors
    push %eax
    push %ebx
    call kernelMain


_stop:
    cli
    hlt
    jmp _stop


.section .bss
.space 2*1024*1024; # 2 MiB
kernel_stack:
```

---

**MakeFile**:

```
GCCPARAMS = -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore
ASPARAMS = --32
LDPARAMS = -melf_i386

objects = loader.o kernel.o



%.o: %.cpp
    gcc $(GCCPARAMS) -c -o $@ $<

%.o: %.s
    as $(ASPARAMS) -o $@ $<

mykernel.bin: linker.ld $(objects)
    ld $(LDPARAMS) -T $< -o $@ $(objects)

mykernel.iso: mykernel.bin
    mkdir iso
    mkdir iso/boot
    mkdir iso/boot/grub
    cp mykernel.bin iso/boot/mykernel.bin
    echo 'set timeout=0'                      > iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo 'set default=0'                     >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo ''                                  >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo 'menuentry "My Operating System" {' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo '  multiboot /boot/mykernel.bin'    >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo '  boot'                            >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo '}'                                 >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    grub-mkrescue --output=mykernel.iso iso
    rm -rf iso

run: mykernel.iso
    (killall VirtualBox && sleep 1) || true
    VirtualBox --startvm 'My Operating System' &

install: mykernel.bin
    sudo cp $< /boot/mykernel.bin
```

---

**types.h**:

```
#ifndef __TYPES_H
#define __TYPES_H

    typedef char                     int8_t;
    typedef unsigned char           uint8_t;
    typedef short                   int16_t;
    typedef unsigned short         uint16_t;
    typedef int                     int32_t;
    typedef unsigned int           uint32_t;
    typedef long long int           int64_t;
    typedef unsigned long long int uint64_t;

#endif
```

Comment: You are a beginner and your first project is an operating system? Don't you think that a slightly simpler project could be a better choice?

Comment: Actually by saying that I am a beginner, I meant I am new to programming operating systems.I love code btw...

I would really love if you drop an answer that fixes the issue :)

Comment: Works here with virtualbox 5.1.26 on Linux Debian Stretch. You sure you created a proper VM called "My Operating System" that specifies the CD-ROM image  correctly?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I would really appreciate if you help me set a proper VM.

Thanks OTW